# can I use blur in a hidden field, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can I use blur in a hidden field in jquery?  if not, how can I track changes in a hidden field

Answer (score 2):

Hidden field is hidden, it won't be visible to a user to change something. Only page author/script can change its value and if that is the case, you can use the `change` event to track changes.

```
$('#hidden_id').change(function(){
  alert('Changed Value: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @Reigel: That's because programatically changing the value of an input does not fire the change event. Which is why I always write it like `$('#elem').val(new_val).trigger('change')`. http://jsfiddle.net/nS4Jt/1/

Comment: @Reigel: He will have to trigger change event explicitly like @Mark commented.

Comment: @Reigel: Yes, but you didn't explain *why* or how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can't in it's normal behavior.

> The **onchange** event occurs when a control *loses the input focus* (blur) and its value has been modified since gaining focus.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange

But you can do it as [Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767138/can-i-use-blur-in-a-hidden-field-jquery/3767164#3767164). Add onchange event then explicitly trigger it every time you change the value of the hidden typed input

Answer (score 0):

The 'change()' event handler doesn't work on hidden input fields. What you can do instead is something along these lines (untested!):

```
function hiddenOnChange(elem, function) {
    if ($(elem).val()!=$(elem).getAttr('oldVal')) {
        function;
    }
    $(elem).attr('oldVal', $(elem).val());

    window.setTimeout(function(){hiddenOnchange(elem, function);}, 100);
}
```

Call this function with your hidden input field and the onchange function. It re-creates the onchange function by comparing the field's "current" value with a previously stored value. If nothing is changed, it re-checks in 100 msecs; If something did change, it will execute your function (I hope ;))

Hope this helps.